# What triggers SqliteDbOpenHelper onUpgrade()?

Tags: android, sqlite

Can someone explain how the onUpgrade function is called within the SqliteDbOpenHelper class.
I'm opening my database but it's not calling the onUpgrade even though I've changed the DB_VERSION.

See following code:

```
public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String TAG = "DbHelper";

    static final String DB_NAME = "caddata.sqlite";
    static final int DB_VERSION = 4;

    private static String DB_PATH = "";
    private Context myContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
        this.myContext = context;

        DB_PATH = "/data/data/"
                + context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName()
                + "/databases/";            
    }

    public DbHelper open() throws SQLException {        
        myDataBase =  getWritableDatabase();

        Log.d(TAG, "DbHelper Opening Version: " +  this.myDataBase.getVersion());
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {

        if (myDataBase != null)
            myDataBase.close();

        super.close();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate called");

        try {           
            createDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        if ( newVersion > oldVersion)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "New database version exists for upgrade.");         
            try {
                Log.d(TAG, "Copying database...");
                copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }       
        }
    }

    public void createDataBase() throws IOException {

        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

        if (!dbExist) {         

            try {
                copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new Error("Error copying database");
            }
        }

        openDataBaseForRead();
    }


    private boolean checkDataBase() {

        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try {
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY
                            | SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);
            Log.d(TAG, "db exists");
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            // database does't exist yet.
            Log.d(TAG, "db doesn't exist");

        }

        if (checkDB != null) {
            checkDB.close();            
        }

        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }


    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

        // Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        // Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        // Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

        myDataBase.setVersion(DB_VERSION);
    }

    public void openDataBaseForRead() throws SQLException {

        // Open the database
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;      
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,  SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    }

    public void openDataBaseForWrite() throws SQLException {

        // Open the database
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;      
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,  SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE | SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS );
    }


}
```

Also see my question detailed here: [Why is onUpgrade() not being invoked on Android sqlite database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7647566/why-is-onupgrade-not-being-invoked-on-android-sqlite-database) for which I didn't get a response.

My main activity opens the database from the helper. It was my assumption that just opening the database will cause onUpgrade() function to be called:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        DbHelper myDbHelper =  new DbHelper(this);

        try {

            myDbHelper.createDataBase();

        } catch (IOException ioe) {

            throw new Error("Unable to create database");

        }

        try {

            myDbHelper.openDataBaseForRead();

        }catch(SQLException sqle){

            throw sqle;

        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Updated after Chris's comment) Pure logic suggests that DB must be upgraded each time it opens with a greater version. Never checked this case, but, as far as I know, `onUpgrade()` is always invoked *during application upgrade* when database version has been changed.

Comment: It checks every time the DB is opened.  Not during application upgrades.

Comment: My point was you can replace a new db file with an old one, run your app and it'll be upgraded on access without upgrading your actual app.  Wasn't trying to be pedantic.

Comment: I got your point and appreciate the new information. Never checked the case of upgrading the database without upgrading the app, and since it didn't work for jaffa, I suggested to check out 'upgrade' option.

Comment: It happen during a call to either getReadableDatabase() or getWriteableDatabase(). http://stackoverflow.com/a/8621774/304270

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the `onCreate()` and `onUpgrade()` function work only when you open a database **`with the SQLiteOpenHelper`**. that means you should call the function `getWritableDatabase()` or `getReadbleDatabase()` to open the database and then maybe it can works normally.

Answer (score 0):

SQLlite database files have an internal version #.  If the API tries to open an existing file and the version is less than some specified one, onUpgrade is called so you can handle it.

Comment: Ok, so why am I not seeing the OnUpgrade function called even though I've incremented the database version?

Comment: Readable DBs can't be upgraded.  Your activity only opens it for read, that may be one reason.

Comment: I changed the call in the startup activity to call openDataBaseForWrite().  My database version set inside the DbHelper class is also set to 2.  However, when I call GetVersion() on the database object it returns 0. Why isn't onUpgrade being called then?

Comment: I am having a similar issue, and during my troubleshooting I am attempting to see where exactly this "internal version #" is.  I pull the database from the emulator (data/data/XXXX/databases/databasename and then look at the file with a database analyzer such as sqliteman.  I do not see any version info.  Thanks for any insight.

Comment: @Mike if you open it up in, eg. SQLite Manager (a plugin for firefox) and go to the DB Settings tab you can see the version #.