# SQLite database version control

Tags: android, sqlite

I read on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163845/is-the-onupgrade-method-ever-called) SO thread(answer from @RobinM) that the SQLiteOpenHelper constructor increases the databases version number everytime its called. Now, i checked the class documentation on the Android developer site and couldn't find any evidence of this. My question is two-fold. Is this behaviour true, and if it is, is there a way of preventing unexpected version number increments that will trigger onUpgrade(), and potentially wipe existing data?

Comment: "I read on this SO thread(answer from @RobinM) that the SQLiteOpenHelper constructor increases the databases version number everytime its called" -- your claim appears nowhere in [that answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30542949/115145).

Comment: scroll down...its not in the first answer, look for RobinM's answer

Comment: I linked to [RobinM's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30542949/115145). I read [RobinM's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30542949/115145). Your claim appears nowhere in [RobinM's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30542949/115145).

Comment: Read my comment on the ticked answer

Comment: you misunderstood the answer. the version is set by you, and is applied when you call the constructor. to avoid wiping data, avoid upgrading your database, or having a migration script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a look at

```
SQLiteOpenHelper(Context context, String name,
        SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version)
```

**You** supply the database version.

---

The constructor gets called when you create your helper and if you supply a `version` higher than the current version, the version of the db will be updated and `onUpgrade` will be called.

The version will **not** increase without your doing. To increase the db version you need to call the constructor with a higher version.

Comment: I see.. @RobinM's answer implied that this may happen under certain conditions. His exact words are: NOTE: calling the DatabaseHelper constructor updates the db version

After the constructor call, the db was tagged with the new version. Kill the app before a call to getWritableDatabase() or getReadableDatabase() and you're on the new version. Thereafter new executions never call the onUpgrade method until DATABASE_VERSION is increased again. (sigh! now it seems ridiculously obvious :)

My suggestion is to add some sort of "checkDatabaseVersion()" to the early stages of your app...."

Comment: however, your explanation makes perfect sense

Comment: @VernonKawonza Robin seems confused. He debugged and got side effects due to stopping app executions at various points. Just read the end of his answer, and it says the same.